# Socket IO randomly send number when idle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, socket.io

i am facing an issue about socket io random send number when idle..

[image]

chat.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var socket = io();
socket.emit("handshaking","");

$('.input').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    var msg = $('.input').val();
    if(msg !=""){
        socket.emit("sendMessage",msg);
        $('.chat-box').append("<p class='msgSend'>"+msg+"</p><br>");
        $('.input').val('');
    }
  }
});

//If handshaking success, print a message to chat box
socket.on("pong", function(msg){
    $('.chat-box').append("<p class='systemMsg'>" + msg + "</p><br>");
});

//Player message
socket.on("getMessage",function(msg){
    $('.chat-box').append("<p class='msgReceive'>"+msg+"</p><br>");
});
});
```

server.js:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var path = require('path');
var mime = require('mime');
var fs = require('fs');
var cache = {};

app.listen(80,function(){
    console.log("Listening to port 80.");
});

function send404(res){
  res.writeHead(404,{'content-type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('Error 404: resource not found.');
  res.end();
}

function sendFile(res, filePath, contents){
  res.writeHead(200,{"content-type": mime.getType(path.basename(filePath))});
  res.end(contents);
}

function serverStatic(res, cache, path){
  if(cache[path]) {
    sendFile(res, path, cache[path]);
  } else {
    fs.exists(path, function(exists) {
      if(exists) {
        fs.readFile(path, function(err,data) {
          if(err) {
            send404(res);
          } else {
            cache[path] = data;
            sendFile(res,path,data);
          }
        });
      } else {
        send404(res);
      }
    });
  }
}

function handler (req, res) {
  var filePath;
  if(req.url == '/'){
    filePath = 'public/index.html';
    console.log(filePath);
  } else {
    filePath = 'public' + req.url;
    console.log(filePath);
  }
  var path = './' + filePath;
  serverStatic(res, cache, path);
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
    socket.broadcast.emit("pong","A user has leave the room.");
  });

  socket.on("handshaking",function(msg){    
      console.log("A user is joined.");
      socket.broadcast.emit("pong", "A user has join the room.");
  });

  socket.on("sendMessage",function(msg){
    socket.broadcast.emit("getMessage",msg);
  });
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chat System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="chat-area">

    <div class="chat-box"></div>

    <input class="input" style="width:100%;" placeholder="Type something"> <!--<button style="">SEND</button>-->

</div>


    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.slim.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/chat.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

I am not sure what's wrong with these code but i am sure that all is working except it will auto send some random number when i idle the browser (the page is still on).

Can someone help me take a look on this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Event-%E2%80%98pong%E2%80%99-1 You're writing the result of the 'pong' event which is the latency in ms. If you remove that it should stop writing numbers to the chat

Comment: Ah i see. I remove the 'pong' and the problem is solved. Thank you very much!